# ¿cómo llamar un alert cuando el usuario lleve el scroll hasta lo más bajo?

Tags: javascript, scroll

Necesito conseguir que cuando el usuario, haciendo scroll, ya no pueda bajar mas (cuando la página termine), se ejecute un alert.

Comment: Esa pregunta ya está respondida aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439725/javascript-how-to-detect-if-browser-window-is-scrolled-to-bottom

Comment: @AsieR_2 este sitio no es sólo una redirección a respuestas en el sitio original. La idea es que las personas encuentren el contenido en español. Pon el código relevante, tradúcela y linkéala si lo consideras relevante, pero construye la respuesta.

Comment: La respuesta original ni si quiera contiene textos en inglés. Me parece redundante y una pérdida de tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() >500) {
      //Aquí colocaras tu alert
    }
  }
);
```

Podrías usar este script, el número `500` lo puedes cambiar por la posición que quieres que tenga el `scroll` para que se aparezca el `alert`.